# Speech to Text Button in AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I have this Layout file for a AlertDialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Bemerkung:"
            android:id="@+id/textView29" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/dialogSpeechText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingRight="34dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sirioriginalstate_teaser"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialogSpeechText"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on the `ImageButton` it will start this method:

```
private void promtSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 6000);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            "Aufnahme...");

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_TO_TEXT_REQUEST);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sprache nicht unterstützt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

After that, the method `onActivityResult` will be called so:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

            EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edittext);
            text.setText(text.getText() + " " + result.get(0));
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View view = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

                ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_imageButton);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setView(view);

                imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        promtSpeechInput();
                    }
                });
```

I used these methods on another Activity. Now I have a AlertDialog and I don't know how to put the Text from Speech Activity into the `EditText` from the alert Dialog?

Comment: Do you want to send the values form the Dialog to EditText in same activity. It is bit confusing. What you want to do actually

Comment: No, i want to send the text to the edittext inside the `AlertDialog`

Comment: In that case pass the text content as arguments. Can you post the code which you are using for alertdialog??

Comment: where do you have EditText inside the AlertDialog?

Comment: changed the ´onActivityResult´ and ´AlertDialog` methods. look at edits... I dont know why, but I don't get any text in my edittext after press the imagebutton

Comment: you should not create EditText inside onActivityResult.

Comment: create findViews inside onCreate of Activity

Comment: How can I add the text which was spoken into the edittext that is inside the AlertDialog?